# choose image to display depending on file date in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out if to show a pause image or the current image. I have an image being uploaded to the server every 15 seconds while something is happening during the day. But if I stop receiving images for 5 minutes I want to display a "paused" image.

But to my understanding I can't access the file state (fs.stat) in react since it's client side. Is there another way to do what I want. This is done inside a react hook.

```
function App() {

function imgSelector() {
  return pause or current image
}

return ( 
<div>
    <img src={imgSelector()} alt="Not found" />
</div>
)}
```

Comment: how do you fetch the img from server?

Comment: The image is in the uploads folder with the projects 'uploads/pause.jpg'

Comment: so just for understanding, `current image` part works fine, and you just have a problem with requiring the local pause img?

Comment: No I have not idea how to do this. I can of course do the onerror etc. To switch images. But I want the function to return either of them.

Comment: If you will add the way you get current image. it will be easier to help you in terms of particular code how to check if the photo giving by the server is "younger" than 5 min, and otherwise return `require("~yourpathto/uploads/pause.jpg")`

Comment: There is no include or anything just now I am getting the image as <img src='uploads/pause.jpg' /> But now I want to return the URL bases on time and date of the one picture.

Comment: Since I couldn't figure out a way to read the file time I opted for deleting the old picture on the server side. This way it will show the pause picture.